# How to create a SWT text field with inactive text as a suffix?

Tags: java, text, swt

I am using Java's SWT toolkit to create a GUI with text field inputs. These input fields require numerical input and have units assigned to them. I'm trying to create a fancy way to integrate units within the field as a fixed suffix to the text, such that the user can only edit the numerical part. I'd also like for the suffix to be greyed out so the user knows it is disabled - something like the following:

[image: A SWT text field with greyed suffix not accessible by the user]

While searching, I saw some solutions with a mask formatter from Swing that might do the trick, but I'm sort of hoping there might be something default with SWT. Any suggestions on how to make this work?

The field is part of a a matrix, so I can't simply add the units to a header label. I suppose I could create another column after the text field that could provide units as a label, but I'm going for something more intuitive and aesthetic.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to group `Text` and `Label` widgets in the same composite, and set the text on the `Label` to the desired suffix:

[image]

The area to the left of the suffix is the single-line text field, which can be edited, and the suffix is a disabled `Label`.

---

```
public class TextWithSuffixExample {

    public class TextWithSuffix {

        public TextWithSuffix(final Composite parent) {
            // The border gives the appearance of a single component
            final Composite baseComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.BORDER);
            baseComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
            final GridLayout baseCompositeGridLayout = new GridLayout(2, false);
            baseCompositeGridLayout.marginHeight = 0;
            baseCompositeGridLayout.marginWidth = 0;
            baseComposite.setLayout(baseCompositeGridLayout);

            // You can set the background color and force it on 
            // the children (the Text and Label objects) to add 
            // to the illusion of a single component
            baseComposite.setBackground(new Color(parent.getDisplay(), new RGB(255, 255, 255)));
            baseComposite.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE);

            final Text text = new Text(baseComposite, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.RIGHT);
            text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

            final Label label = new Label(baseComposite, SWT.NONE);
            label.setEnabled(false);
            label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, false, true));
            label.setText("kg/m^3");
        }

    }

    final Display display;
    final Shell shell;

    public TextWithSuffixExample() {
        display = new Display();
        shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        shell.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        new TextWithSuffix(shell);
    }

    public void run() {
        shell.setSize(200, 100);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new TextWithSuffixExample().run();
    }

}
```

Comment: What about a custom MaskFormatter? It has been a long time  since I worked with SWT, but Nebula has this formatter available

Comment: @LppEdd Sorry, I'm not familiar with MaskFormatter (or really Nebula in general) so I won't be much help there...

Comment: Not a problem. See here for example https://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/formattedtext/formattedtext.php

Comment: Interesting... That might work, although at a glance it looks like it's all a single text field, so I'm not sure how you'd be able to achieve an immutable suffix without doing some extra legwork.

Comment: You'd absolutely need that extra work ;) Mine was just a hint/cuoriosity.

Comment: Yea, looks like there's some pretty neat stuff in Nebula though, so you might be able to get a more robust solution with something similar to that formatter!

Comment: I proposed Nebula because years ago I worked on a product which made extensive usage of those widgets/enhancements. They were rock solid. Anyway yours is a good solution

Comment: I had to modify some coloring and added a listener, but this is a really flexible solution that did the trick. Many thanks!

Comment: Since the text and label fields are actually separate entities, clicking on the label does not let you start typing on the text side. To give the full illusion that this is one entity, is there some way to make it so that when I click on the label portion (kg/m^3 in example), it sends the cursor to the end of the text field? Perhaps with a listener?

Comment: @WhiteFish yea, if you add a selection listener to the label, that should work. Inside the listener you can set the focus to the text field - I think there’s a setFocus() method on the Text class? Something like that.

Comment: I added a listener that applies text.setFocus() and text.setSelection(text.toString().length()). Now when the user clicks on the unit part, the mouse jumps to the end of the text part. It now very cleanly appears as one field. So thanks!